# Getting 3 warnings when using PickerView

Tags: ios, warnings, uipickerview

When I use this code I get three warning at the implementation saying that  incomplete implementation,Method pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController in protocool not implemented, Method pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController in protocool not implemented.   I do not know why this is happening

This is my header file

```
    IBOutlet UIPickerView     *SaveTopicker;
    NSMutableArray            *arraygenre;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *imagePreview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *saveImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *captureImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *cameraSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *pickerViewContainer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *BGScrollView;
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)closeButton:(id)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImage *yourImage;



- (IBAction)switchCamera:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)snapImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

This is my implementaion file.
    @implementation ViewController

```
@synthesize accelerometer, stillImageOutput, imagePreview, captureImage, cameraSwitch, pickerViewContainer;

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == genre)
        return [arraygenre count];

    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == genre)
        return [arraygenre objectAtIndex:row];
    return 0;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;


}

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 307, 320, 261);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)closeButton:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    pickerViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 261);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //fetch Category Name from the array used to fill the Picker View
    NSString *categoryName= [arraygenre objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:categoryName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:fPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    UIImage *image = captureImage.image;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:fPath atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: Where do you set the data source?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your class as implementing the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol, which obligates you to implement these methods.  Remove the reference to the protocol if you didn't actually want to be a data source for a `UIPageViewController`, or implement the methods if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the UIPicker Delegate but instead doing a PageControl delegate. To undo this you must find where you declared the PageviewControllerDelegate and remove it. Then inset the picker delegate.